# Powershell - Add data from one CSV into new column and rows of another CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to add data from one CSV file into another CSV file with Powershell

Expected output Example:

```
Network, Agent
Net1, Agent1
Net2, Agent2
```

Currently I am only managing to add the data like this which defeats the point:

```
Network
Net1
Net2
Agent
Agent1
Agent2
```

The reason for this is my program will need to specify the agents in an already generated CSV file.

Could anybody advise how I can add an additional column and then fill the data in the next rows?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both CSV files have the same number of data rows, you can use [Import-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7) and [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7). Then loop through each data row simultaneously.

```
$network = Import-Csv network.csv
$agent = Import-Csv agent.csv
0..($network.Count-1) |
    Select @{n='Network';e={$network[$_].Network}},@{n='Agent';e={$agent[$_].Agent}} |
        Export-Csv output.csv -NoType
```

`$_` is the current object in the pipeline, which iterates through all of the objects.

---

If you want to add a new property to an existing custom object, you can still use calculated properties.

```
Import-Csv network.csv | Foreach-Object {
    $agent = 'Agent Value' # some code to get the agent
    $_ | Select-Object Network,@{n='Agent';e={$agent}}
} | Export-Csv output.csv -NoType
```